# Sprint Rest AuthenticationPrincipal returns customUser with only null values

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to get the currently logged in user (basic auth) in a spring boot REST backend:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someURL", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Map someMethod(
  Authentication auth,   //  <==== works
  @AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "liquidoUserModel") UserModel liquidoUserModel    
)  
{
  log.debug(auth.getPrincipal())  // <==== THIS WORKS
  log.debug(liquidoUserModel)  // <==== returns an intance with empty fields
}
```

Here is my custom **UserModel**

```
@Data  // Lombok magic for all the getters and setters
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserModel {
   @Id
   Long id;

   @NonNull
   @Column(unique = true)
   public String email;

   [...]
}
```

And this is my **UserDetailsService**

```
public class LiquidoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
  @Autowired
  UserRepo userRepo;

  @Override
  public LiquidoAuthUser loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserModel userModel = userRepo.findByEmail(email);
    return new LiquidoAuthUser(userModel.getEmail(), userModel.getPasswordHash(), getGrantedAuthorities(userModel), userModel);
  }
}
```

And finally the **LiquidoAuthUser**

```
public class LiquidoAuthUser extends User {  
  private UserModel liquidoUserModel;

  public LiquidoAuthUser(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, UserModel liquidoUserModel) {
    super(username, password, authorities);
    this.liquidoUserModel = liquidoUserModel;
  }

  public UserModel getLiquidoUserModel() {
    return liquidoUserModel;
  }

  public void setLiquidoUserModel(UserModel userModel) {
    this.liquidoUserModel = userModel;
  }
}
```

And of course I have the @EnableWebMvc annotation on my main SpringApplication class.

**My problem:** How can I get the currently authenticated custom UserModel in the REST handler?

The strange thing: I actually can get my custom user from the Authentication auth object. Why does the @AuthenticationPrincipal not work?

I am using spring-security-4.1.3-RELEASE

Full code is open source at https://github.com/Doogiemuc/liquido-backend-spring

Answer (score 1):

I tried and debug your code but not able to find issue of
@AuthenticationPrincipal. Typically this annotation is resolved by AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver class of spring security web annotation. By using @EnableWebSecurity you will automatically have this added to your Spring MVC configuration. Need to be debug more on AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver that for time being I will suggest go with Authentication class and get your object.